# How to continue the sequence of the unique numbers in the excel sheet after closing the userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am facing a problem in getting the sequence of the unique numbers(Serial number) when the userform is closed and opened later on. Firstly, when I fill the data in the userform everything is captured in the excel sheet perfectly with correct sequence; if I close the userform and run the code by filling the userform with new data the unique ID's are again starting from "1" but not according to the excel sheet row number which was previously saved.

[image: IMG1]

Below is the code I tried:

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim lr As Long

    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Book2.xlsx")

    Dim Database As Worksheet
    Set Database = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    eRow = Database.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    lr = Database.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        If IsEmpty(.Range("A1")) Then
            .Range("A1").Value = 0
        Else
            Database.Cells(lr + 1, 1) = Val(Database.Cells(lr, 1)) + 1
        End If
    End With

    Database.Cells(eRow, 4).Value = cmbls.Text
    Database.Cells(eRow, 2).Value = txtProject.Text
    Database.Cells(eRow, 3).Value = txtEovia.Text
    Database.Cells(eRow, 1).Value = txtUid.Text

    Call UserForm_Initialize
    WB.SaveAs ("C:\Users\Desktop\Book2.xlsx")

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim maxNumber

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        ' don't run when more than one row is changed
        If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        ' if column A in the current row has a value, don't run
        If Cells(Target.Row, 1) > 0 Then Exit Sub

        ' get the highest number in column A, then add 1 and write to the
        ' current row, column A
        maxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))
        Target.Offset(0, -1) = maxNumber + 1
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With txtUid
        .Value = Format(Val(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) + 1, "0000")
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    With txtProject
        .Value = ""
        .SetFocus
    End With
End Sub
```

In this image if you see unique id's are repeating 1 and 2, but I need as 1,2,3,4....

[image: IMG2]

Comment: Perhaps, instead of calculating the max number you need to use `ROW()` function? Like this: `With Rang("A2"): .Formula = "=ROW()-1": .Value=.Value: End With`

Comment: I tried as you said but no change, can you please edit in my code.

Comment: You are showing us 3 macros. Can you explain how they are related? Do we really need to see all 3 of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is where the issue is coming from. You need to re-calculate the last row every time the user form is `Initialized`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Database")
    With txtUid
        .Value = Format(ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp) + 1, "0000")
        .Enabled = False
    End With

    With txtProject
        .Value = ""
        .SetFocus
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it worked perfect for my code, I undertood where I was wrong. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It's always risky to use row numbers or [max range value +1] as a sequence number.
Safer to use something like a name scoped to the worksheet, which has a value you can increment.  Then the sequence is independent of your data.

E.g.

```
Function GetNextSequence(sht As Worksheet) As Long
    Const SEQ_NAME As String = "SEQ"
    Dim nm As Name, rv As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set nm = sht.Names(SEQ_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'add the name if it doesn't exist
    If nm Is Nothing Then
        Set nm = sht.Names.Add(Name:=SEQ_NAME, RefersToR1C1:="=0")
    End If

    rv = Evaluate(nm.Value) + 1
    nm.Value = rv
    GetNextSequence = rv
End Function
```